# Cómo contar las palabras que son iguales que la primera palabra en C

Tags: c

Necesito realizar este programa pero no consigo acabarlo.

Tengo que, dada una frase que el usuario me introduce por pantalla, contar cuántas palabras son iguales que al primera palabra (en cuanto a longitud se refiere).

Debo de utilizar `strlen` y `strcmp`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void countWords(char arr[]);

void main() {
    char arr[300];
    countWords();   
}

void countWords(char arr[]) {
    int count = 0;
        int i, j;
        
        printf("Introduce un string: \n");

        for(i = 0; i < arr[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            scanf("%s", &arr[i]);
        }

        for(j = 0; j < strlen(arr); j++) {
            if (strcmp(arr[0], arr[i]) == 0) {
                // Son iguales
                count ++;
            }
        }
        
        printf ("There are %d words that are the same as the first word: ", count);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

estabas cerca de conseguirlo, solo hay un par de errores:

1. En la linea 8, falta pasarle el parámetro `arr` a la función `countWords`, debería quedar así: `countWords(arr);`.
2. El bucle for de la linea 17 y su condición son medio confusos, seria mejor reemplazar:

   ```c
   for(i = 0; i < arr[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        scanf("%s", &arr[i]);
   }
   ```

   por: `gets(arr);`, esto básicamente lee string incluyendo espacios y lo almacena en `arr`.
3. En la linea 22, debería utilizarse la variable `j` en vez de `i` quedando `arr[j]`.
4. Si es que obligatoriamente si o si debes utilizar `strlen` y `strcmp`, entonces se complica un poco el tema, ya que `strcmp` compara strings y no caracteres, por lo tanto deberías convertir `arr[0]` y `arr[j]` en strings antes de compararlos, podrías hacer esto reemplazando:

   ```c
   for(j = 0; j < strlen(arr); j++) {
        if (strcmp(arr[0], arr[j]) == 0) {
             // Son iguales
             count ++;
        }
   }
   ```

   por:

   ```c
   char char1[2] = "\0\0", char2[2] = "\0\0";
   char1[0] = arr[0];
   for(j = 0; j < strlen(arr); j++) {
       char2[0] = arr[j];
       if (strcmp(char1, char2) == 0) {
           // Son iguales
           count ++;
       }
   }
   ```

   Personalmente, y si pudiera evitar utilizar `strlen` y `strcmp`, me gustaría mas la siguiente opción:

   ```c
   for(j = 1; arr[j] != '\0'; j++) {
        if (arr[0] == arr[j]) {
           // Son iguales
           count ++;
         }
    }
   ```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo!!!!!

Comment: `gets` es una función insegura y obsoleta. Un reemplazo podría ser [fgets](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/).